# Python: Can't find file even though file referenced exists

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-10

I'm getting this error when trying to run a Python script. Is it saying that it can't find subprocess.py? Because I found it in the location it's listing there, so I doubt that's the issue. What file can't it find?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Projects\PythonMathPlots\MandelbrotVideoGenerator.py", line 201, in <module>
    run( ['open', 'MandelbrotZoom.mp4'] )
  File "C:\Users\Aaron\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 472, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "C:\Users\Aaron\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 775, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\Aaron\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 1178, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Comment: I think maybe your `'MandelbrotZoom.mp4` file, is `D:\Projects\PythonMathPlots\MandelbrotVideoGenerator.py` on your path?

Comment: probably it can't find file `open` or `MandelbrotZoom.mp4`. You may have to add full path to both.

Comment: @whatwhatwhat What is the **`code`** that you ran? In order to help you with your query, it will be helpful to see the code and the error/output both.

Comment: I'm used to `open` being a Mac thing, not a Windows thing.

Comment: This question is not a Sublime Text question, it's a Python question. It would be a Sublime question if the problem was that Sublime doesn't execute your script, but it's running it and the issue is in the code of the script itself.

Comment: Note also that `open` is a MacOS specific command to open a file in the associated application. On Windows the equivalent command is `start`, so based on the error you're getting one issue is that you can't execute `open` because it doesn't exist on windows (Windows looks for it and can't find it).

Answer (score 1):

You may need to put the full path in the `run(...)` command, to the `open` file, and the path to the .mp4 file as well.

Most likely, `open` does not exist on your system and you have to use the name of the video player software instead.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the user you're running the script as has read permission for the file.

Answer (score 0):

You may also try with `subprocess.Popen(args, shell=True)`. The use of **`shell=True`** may be useful.

Also, use a path defined as `path = os.path.join(filepath, filename)` and then before passing the `path` to `Popen`, assert if `os.path.exists(path)==True`.

But note that there are some downsides to using `shell=True`:

1. [Actual meaning of 'shell=True' in subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess)
2. https://medium.com/python-pandemonium/a-trap-of-shell-true-in-the-subprocess-module-6db7fc66cdfd